# How to add additional filter to Directus CMS request Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, directus

I have an issue, where I am not able to add additional search query fields in the request url.

I have a function, that is supposed to get career offers from the CMS, in the code below:

```
  getCareerOffers() {
    return this.getItems<CareerOffer>('career_offers', ['*', 'image.*', 'content_side_image.*']);
  }
```

After reading Directus docs, there is a possibility to add an additional query field, to be more specific, in the form of adding `[comparator][eq]` field, which would look like this:

```
  getCareerOffers() {
    return this.getItems<CareerOffer>('career_offers', ['*', 'image.*', 'content_side_image.*'], {
      '[company][eq]': 'company',
    });
  }
```

The issue I am facing, is that I do not really know how to properly proceed. I have been advised, that I should be joining the fields within the function.

Here is how the function looks so far:

```
private getItems<T>(collection: string, fields?: string[], filter?: Record<string, string>): Observable<T[]> {
    if (!this.cachedObservables[collection]) {


      const prefixedFilters = {}

      const params = {
        ...(fields ? { fields: fields.join() } : prefixedFilters),
        filter: Object.keys(filter).reduce((filtersKey) => {
          const prefixedFilterKey = `filters${filtersKey}`

          prefixedFilters[prefixedFilterKey] = filter[filtersKey]
        }),
      };

      this.cachedObservables[collection] = this.http
        .get<CmsItems<T[]>>(`${this.apiUrl}/items/${collection}`, { params })
        .pipe(
          map(response => response.data),
          publishReplay(1),
          refCount(),
        );
    }

    return this.cachedObservables[collection];
  }
```

Now, where I am stuck is in the `params` object, where I can not figure out, how to properly format the filter value.

`Object.keys(filter)` returns an array with with `0: [company][eq]` inside it.

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Comment: Are you able to achieve this in Postman, outside of Angular?

Comment: Yes, I am. I was able to solve it this morning, will post an answer in a bit,

Comment: @justintimeza I have added an answer, that worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. I was writing my array method wrong. This was the solution  that I came up with:

```
    if (!this.cachedObservables[collection]) {
      const prefixedFilters = {};

      Object.keys(filter).reduce((prefixedFilter, filterKey) => {
        prefixedFilters[`filter${filterKey}`] = filter[filterKey];

        return prefixedFilters;
      }, prefixedFilters);

      const params = {
        ...(fields && { fields: fields.join() }),
        ...prefixedFilters,
      };

      this.cachedObservables[collection] = this.http
        .get<CmsItems<T[]>>(`${this.apiUrl}/items/${collection}`, { params })
        .pipe(
          map(response => response.data),
          publishReplay(1),
          refCount(),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Great. Good tip with Directus is that the native UI makes API calls in the same was that you can in your app, so you can find answers in the Chrome dev tools, especially to more obscure API queries.